# Trouble Accessing scope variable in ng-template under script

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to design inline editing template using angular.I have followed this tutorial

http://blog.shubhamsaxena.com/creating-simple-inline-editing-with-angularjs/

My Code is

```
<table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="table-row" ng-repeat="admin in admins" ng-include="getTemplate(admin)"> 
                <script type="text/ng-template" id="display">
                    <td class="table-img">
                       <img src="images/in.jpg" alt="" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="table-text">
                        <h6>{{admin.firstname}} {{admin.lastname}}</h6>
                        <p>{{admin.email}}</p>
                        <p>{{admin.phone}}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="fam">{{admin.dept_name}}</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="march">
                        <button class="btn-transparent btn" ng-click="editAdmin(admin)"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x"></i></button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn-transparent btn"><i class="fa fa-remove fa-2x"></i></button>
                    </td>
                </script>
                <script type="text/ng-template" id="edit">

                </script>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

angular js code

```
$scope.getTemplate = function (admin) {
        if (admin.id === $scope.selected.id){
            $scope.template = 'edit';
        }
        else{
            $scope.template = 'display';
        }
        return $scope.template;
    };
    $scope.editAdmin = function (admin) {
        $scope.selected = angular.copy(admin);
    };
```

But when I run this it gives me 404 error in console

www.ip-address/dashboard/principal/display

"display" is my script id you can verify in the 1st snippet.

My question is why it is searching "display" id in the url.

scope variable admins has data but it do not accessed when I write under script.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

404 means not found

```
 $scope.getTemplate = function (employee) {
        if (employee.empID === $scope.selected.empID){
            return 'edit';
        }
        else return 'display';
    };
```

getTemplate if the the Id already exist then it will open in Edit script or else will show in display script

HTMl

```
<tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees" ng-include="getTemplate(employee)">
                    <script type="text/ng-template" id="display">
                        <td>{{employee.empName}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.empEmail}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.empSalary | currency:"&#8377;"}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.active | active}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editEmployee(employee)">Edit</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteEmployee(employee)">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </script>
                    <script type="text/ng-template" id="edit">
                        <td><input type="text" ng-model=employee.empName class="form-control input-sm"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" ng-model=employee.empEmail class="form-control input-sm"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" ng-model=employee.empSalary class="form-control input-sm"/></td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model=employee.active>
                                <option value='1'>Yes</option>
                                <option value='0'>No</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateEmployee(employee)">Save</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="reset()">Cancel</button>
                        </td>
                    </script>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Comment: Yes, but in console it gives me 404 error www.ip-address/dashboard/principal/display

Comment: create a fiddle it will be helpful to fix